# How to create a new controller in monologue blog engine in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines, monologue

I'm trying to create a description page for blog post authors. I've created a route:

```
mount Monologue::Engine, at: '/blog'

#create routes for monologue
Monologue::Engine.routes.draw do
    get 'p/:name', to: 'authors#show', as: :author
end
```

And I've created a controller in app/controllers/monologue:

```
class Monologue::AuthorsController
    def show
        puts "in show method"
    end
end
```

I keep getting this error:

```
undefined method `action' for Monologue::AuthorsController:Class
```

Long story short: how do I generate a controller within monologue?

Comment: What's your output from $rake routes from the app where you are mounting the engine?

Answer (score -1):

```
Monologue::Engine.routes.draw do
  get '/posts/:author_id', to: "posts#author_posts", as: "author_posts"
end

class Monologue::PostsController < Monologue::ApplicationController
  def author_posts
    @posts = Monologue::Post.where(:user_id => params[:author_id],).order(created_at: :desc)
    @author = Monologue::User.find_by_id(params[:author_id])
  end
end
```

This is how you add a controller action.

Comment: please add some explanation about you are answering.